# Are there any other web developement / design environments available, that are similar to Dashcode?

Tags: dashcode

Are there any other web developement / design environments available, that are similar to Dashcode?

Some that provide similar HTML + CSS part based development with Javascript as glue using the same model-view-controller paradigm?

Comment: I discourage the use of Dashcode and all other click-and-drag web design tools (that means you, Dreamweaver!). They don't teach you *how* to code. They code *for you*.

Comment: I agree. However we can't have everyone build a Javascript MVC framework from scratch every time they build a simple web page, can we. Any mildly advanced Dashcode app will require a fair bit of coding on the side. I actually like the approach they take. Using tried and tested design patterns together with tried and tested web (future) standards. :D

Comment: From scratch? Use a pre-built one. I'm against click-and-drag web design tools, but I can't really picture a click-and-drag framework tool.

Comment: Jeez the guy asked for "similar to Dashcode" not "Please give me a lecture on how to program" I like Dashcode, it make me productive and reduces my costs to clients and mean people i pay to do work for me leave me with code that is halfway readable when i need to maintain it. However i can also write, with vi, html, css and JavaScript. In fact if pushed i can still hack quite good assembler. But i do like to sleep and see the sun from time to time, so lighten up on the prescriptiveness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[extjs](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/)

[phonegap](http://www.phonegap.com/)

[iui](http://code.google.com/p/iui/)

The fist two are similar iui is more just a framework. However it will get you started to look at options. They all have good and bad elements.

[See here for more frameworks](http://www.howitt.com/?p=222)